# Рандом из нескольких массивов py

Tags: python, случайные-числа, бот, telegram

Добырый день, подскажите пожалуйста, как рандомно выбрать не из одного массива а сразу из нескольких, причём из каждого по одному? Вот мой код, но тут только из одного выбирает.

```
import random
import telebot
def send_message():

  FirstName = ["Имя1", 'Имя2','Имя3']
  LastName = ['Фамилия1', 'Фамилия2', 'Фамилия3',]
  SecondName = ['Отчество1','Отчество2','Отчество3']
  bot.send_message(chat_id, random.choice(FirstName))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
message = random.choice(FirstName) + random.choice(LastName) + random.choice(SecondName)
bot.send_message(chat_id, message)
```

А еще лучше использовать f-строки

```
message = f'{random.choice(FirstName)} {random.choice(LastName)} {random.choice(SecondName)}'
bot.send_message(chat_id, message)
```